# find nth max salary from a table without using cte, top, subquery

Tags: sql-server

In an interview I was asking to find nth maximum salary without using CTE, top, sub query. I am confused. Is any other way to do.

And another question,
2 tables having identical columns with Identity ID column. When copying records from table1 to table2, the ID values also should be moved. For example, if table1 having the IDs 1,3,5,7.. the same ID values should be moved to table2 ID column.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. If you have multiple questions, post multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

He is looking for new feature [OFFSET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx).

Query to get 10th salary

```
SELECT * FROM dbp.Empsalary AS P
ORDER BY P.salary desc 
OFFSET 9 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Note: N -1 =9 here

Second : Question he is looking for do you know  [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql)

you have to SET IDENTITY_INSERT off for second table.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd Problem, It can Be achieved By Turning ON The IDENTITY_INSERT for the Destination Table. Like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Val VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO TableA(Val)
VALUES('ABC'),('HIJ'),('XYZ')


SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB on
INSERT INTO TableB(Id,Val)
SELECT Id,Val FROM TableA
```